# Mule best practice?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I would like to build a component that other developers can plugin in to MuleStudio and use to process files. It will expose a variety of methods which process the incoming file and return a new file. I want to make sure I'm going in the right direction with my implementation of this, and would appreciate any advice about best practices.

From my reading, it seems that I should use Mule Devkit to create a Module. This module can contain a variety of Processor methods. I then package with the maven command, and it can be installed as a plugin.

Some specific questions:

-Should I use Processors or Transformers, is there any difference in this case?

-Should I create multiple modules each with one Processor/Transformer, or one module with all the Processors/Transfromers?

-I would like the file to be able to be supplied generically (from an email, http, local file system, etc...). What should the parameter and return of my Processors be?  Can I use InputStream as a param and OutputStream as my return, and then expect users to use the proper Endpoints/transformers to provide the InputStream.  Or should I supply a variety of methods that take a variety of parameters, and perform the converison myself?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your requirement i can suggest please go ahead with MuleSoft Connector DevKit which in the box contains so many cool features and easy to build and install.

You can give it a try once , and achieve your business needs:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/

Creating Anypoint Connector

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/creating-an-anypoint-connector-project